# Unusual use of the Ternary Operator

Tags: c, ternary

I'm a newbie to C, I understand why ternary operators can be useful, less code than if/else blocks.

I have been given some C code to maintain, and one thing I've noticed is the previous programmer used ternary operators like this

```
myInt = (!myInt) ? MACRO1 : MACRO2;
```

Does this accomplish exactly the same thing as this:

```
myInt = myInt ? MACRO2 : MACRO1;
```

Is this just a style thing? Perhaps it makes sense to think "if not" myInt, instead of "if"?

Comment: Why would you stick macros in a ternary operator o.O

Comment: Both are the same, it's only style.

Comment: They are exactly the same. However, if the original variable name is better, then leave it alone.

Comment: Its primary usfulness is not "less code", but rather that it is an operator rather than a construct, so can be used anywhere an expression is valid, including function arguments.

Comment: @nhahtdh what do you mean "if the original variable name is better"?

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito: For example, if the original variable name doesn't contain negative word (e.g. `hasProperty`, `isProperty`, as opposed to `isNotProperty`), then using logical NOT operator seems to make more sense.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, great point, thanks for the response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this code accomplishes exactly the same thing. It just depends on the logic used when writing the condition - so it can be chalked up to style (i.e. whichever is easier for you to think).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.  It seems as though the originator of that code wanted to make the expression slightly more confusing than it needed to be.

Comment: I agree, the weird thing is he / she consistently used it, sorry I had to mark the other answer as correct, just since he was first. :( thnx for the response tho

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the second example as it is not using reverse logic, therefore easier to understand and less clutter.

```
myInt = myInt ? MACRO2 : MACRO1;
```